# Running iBGP without IGP

Tags: routing, bgp

Given following setup:
[image: network layout]

Configuration of the routers is very straight forward. Router BGP1:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback9
 ip address 9.9.9.9 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
router bgp 1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 redistribute connected
 neighbor 10.0.0.2 remote-as 1
 neighbor 10.0.0.2 next-hop-self
```

Router BGP2:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 ip address 20.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
router bgp 1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 redistribute connected
 neighbor 10.0.0.1 remote-as 1
 neighbor 10.0.0.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 20.0.0.2 remote-as 1
 neighbor 20.0.0.2 next-hop-self
```

Router BGP3:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 ip address 20.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
router bgp 1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 redistribute connected
 neighbor 20.0.0.1 remote-as 1
 neighbor 20.0.0.1 next-hop-self
```

So I added interface loopback9 to Router BGP1 to see if this gets across BGP3. But this is not the case. I can see the route coming into BGP2 from BGP1:

```
BGP2#show ip route bgp | begin 1.0
      1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B        1.1.1.1 [200/0] via 10.0.0.1, 00:10:07
      3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B        3.3.3.3 [200/0] via 20.0.0.2, 00:10:07
      9.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B        9.9.9.9 [200/0] via 10.0.0.1, 00:10:07
```

But this does not get advertised to Router BGP3:

```
BGP2#show ip bgp neighbors 20.0.0.2 advertised-routes | begin Networ
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  2.2.2.2/32       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.0.0.0/24      0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  20.0.0.0/24      0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
```

IGP synchonisation is disabled on all devices:

```
BGP2# show ip protocols | include synch
  IGP synchronization is disabled
```

So how can i fix this? I know you are supposed to be running an IGP under BGP, but lets just assume that this is not possible in this scenario. What are my options?

Comment: See RFC7938 for details on how to use BGP without an IGP (or, more accurately, BGP as your IGP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iBGP rule is that an iBGP router cannot learn an iBGP originated prefix from an iBGP neighbor. If BGP2 learns a prefix via iBGP from either BGP1 or BGP3, it cannot advertise that prefix to the other router.

You must have a full mesh for iBGP, or you could use a mitigation (route reflector or confederations). You could create a tunnel between BGP1 and BGP3 to create a full mesh. You could also configure BGP2 as a route reflector.

Answer (score 1):

Ron Maupin is correct in this regard. What you have is a partial mesh of iBGP peers.

The behavior of iBGP is that when a Router advertises a route to an iBGP peer, that iBGP peer does not advertise those same prefixes to another IBGP peer.

Two solutions for this issue are:

Creating a full mesh of iBGP peers

Or

Redistributing your BGP routes into your IGP ( with BGP synchronization enabled on your iBGP peers)

Comment: I advise you to not redistribute from BGP into an IGP in a production network unless you know exactly what you are doing.  IGPs are not designed to handle the hundreds of thousands of routes in a typical BGP table, and horrific outages can result.  In the lab, of course, it all seems to work fine.